# Go from application to camera take photo and store in a column in database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, camera, android-camera

I have a requirement that i want to go from my application to the camera and then the photo take should be stored on the database, then from the database i want to show the column data within a list view with other data. I have an idea about the list view, using an image view etc... i just don't know where to start with regards to accessing the camera and storing it to a column in the database?? any tips or even a tutorial that i could look at which would be helpful?

```
public class CameraAPI extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

public Camera camera;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;



public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.acccam);
    SurfaceHolder holder = surface.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

        public void tackPhoto(View view){
            takePicture();

    }




public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mediaRecorder == null){
        try{
            camera = camera.open();
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();

        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}



public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
}

public void takePicture(){
    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);

}


ShutterCallback shutterCallback= new ShutterCallback()
{
    public void onShutter(){

    }
};

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback(){
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){

        }
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback(){
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try{
                outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Image.jpg");
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e){
                Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
};
}
```

this is my camera API code... is there anyway to tweak this then to add to a database instead of to the sd card?

thanks,

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Start [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) for reference to using the camera, then read [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) to learn about using an `SQLite` database.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following link. It's a good example of capturing images from your application:
[Capture image from your app using camera](https://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/)

Once you have the path of the captured image, you can save it in your database.

Comment: hmmm ok ive created my own API.. using the camera.. i realize that this is saving the image to the sd card.. so is there a way i can tweak this slightly to add the image to the database instead ?

Answer (score 0):

1. First save taken pic in device's cache memory, convert this saved image in ByteArray and them save it in Database. Do this in background thread so that UI thread should not be disturbed.
   Do not forget to delete that image from cache once your image is saved in your database.
2. Or try directly saving this passed byte array to your database

   values.put(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.ImageColumn, data);

and insert this data to your database.

Hope this will work.

Go through the [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html) which will helps to save image in database